# Loading property file on openshift / linux hosting (Spring)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, openshift

I am loading my Application Configuration property file like this

```
PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(propertiesFilename));
```

This code is working fine on my local environment and I have my property file here

[image: Project Structure]

But on production it is not able to pick the property file. Where should I keep it so that it works on both local and production with same code.

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the production WAR and see if the properties file is there. If it's not then it means that the build process as some logic (maven profile, ant If clause) that removes the file depending on the environment.

Try to check the pom.xml or ant.xml files for resource filtering functionality that might have removed the file, and replaced it with for example `app-prod.properties`.